# How to handle multiple AudioPlayers in flutter

Tags: flutter, audio, audio-player

I am building a chat app and I need to build as many audio players as there are in the chat. I tried to use `just_audio` and `audio_waveforms` but neither of them helped me. With just_audio, I couldn't control multiple audio players, my approach was that for each audio message I would create an AudioPlayer with an id in a map. with this I could control each one of the audio players but there were some issues with the library itself so I quitted using it. `audio_waveforms`, it couldn't find my audio at all in `assets/audio/1.wav`. I also tried using path_provider like this:

```
final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      await player.preparePlayer(
        path: '${directory.path}/$path',
        shouldExtractWaveform: true,
        noOfSamples: 100,
      );
```

but same issue. Can someone with experience in this field tell me what is the best approach for playing multiple audio players **NOT** simultaneously and what package or the code he used for this.

**EDIT**

I tried putting the folder in the same folder as the file and it didn't gave me an error but it didn't work, it just gave me a vertical line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the sample code for playing `multiple sounds` from a `ListView`.

Firstly, download my assets from [here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/b8a289cd752d40850014bd3d9e68b3de20230912114802/59d4a1).

This will add a line like this to your package's `pubspec.yaml` (and run an implicit flutter pub get):

```
dependencies:
  just_audio: ^0.9.35
```

Also, in the `pubspec.yaml` file, do these configurations:

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/sound1.mp3
    - assets/sound2.mp3
    - assets/sound3.mp3
    - assets/sound4.mp3
    - assets/sound5.mp3
```

Copy & paste these codes into the `main.dart` file:

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import "package:just_audio/just_audio.dart";

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  int playIndex = -1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 5,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return ListTile(
              dense: true,
              leading: const Icon(Icons.music_note),
              title: Text("Sound ${index + 1}"),
              subtitle: Text("Tap to play sound ${index + 1}"),
              trailing: Icon(
                playIndex == index ? Icons.stop_circle : Icons.play_circle,
              ),
              onTap: () async {
                if (playIndex == index) {
                  await MyAudioService.instance.stop();
                  playIndex = -1;
                  setState(() {});
                } else {
                  final String soundPath = "assets/sound${index + 1}.mp3";
                  await MyAudioService.instance.play(
                    path: soundPath,
                    startedPlaying: () {
                      playIndex = index;
                      setState(() {});
                    },
                    stoppedPlaying: () {
                      playIndex = -1;
                      setState(() {});
                    },
                  );
                }
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyAudioService {
  MyAudioService._();
  static final MyAudioService instance = MyAudioService._();

  final AudioPlayer player = AudioPlayer();

  Future<void> play({
    required String path,
    required Function() startedPlaying,
    required Function() stoppedPlaying,
  }) async {
    await stop();
    await player.setAsset(path);
    startedPlaying();
    await player.play();
    await player.stop();
    stoppedPlaying();
    return Future<void>.value();
  }

  Future<void> stop() async {
    if (player.playing) {
      await player.stop();
    } else {}
    return Future<void>.value();
  }
}
```

Comment: I found the problem which is not related to the package. I am using BLoC as a state management lib. I had a problem where I was rebuilding all the instances of my AudioMsg class, so I added an id for each class and check if that id is the same in the BLoC, if it is the same, it rebuilds that class, if not which means it is a different widget, it doens't rebuild.